# C# XML XPath Query Not working

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I cant get my Xpath query to work though on paper it should be right. I even tried to get a single node without the attribute and could not even get this ...

> > What am I doing wrong ?

[image: Built result trx (cml) format]

```
var trxXml = new XmlDocument();
trxXml.Load(InputTrxFile);
XmlElement root = trxXml.DocumentElement;

var unitTestResult = trxXml.GetElementsByTagName("UnitTestResult");
foreach (XmlElement runinfo in unitTestResult)
{
    // Find failed tests, works fine then... 
     string TestName = runinfo.GetAttribute("testName"); // works fine 
     // Want to find equivalent TestDefinitions/UnitTest
     /* Tried
        TestRun/TestDefinitions/UnitTest[@name='thetest']
        /TestRun/TestDefinitions/UnitTest[@name='thetest']
        TestDefinitions/UnitTest[@name='thetest']
        /TestDefinitions/UnitTest[@name='thetest']
        UnitTest[@name='thetest']
        variations with no attribute test JUST to get a node 
        Example http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-attribute-value/
      */
    var xpath = string.Format(@"/TestRun/TestDefinitions/UnitTest[@name='{0}']", TestName); 
    XmlNode node = trxXml.SelectSingleNode(xpath);      
    XmlNode node2 = root.SelectSingleNode(xpath);   
    // These all return null
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/xpath/2324/namespaces#t=201608050604347342848

Answer (score 3):

Any query that begins with a `/` represents an absolute path, i.e. it is from the *root of the document*.  It seems your `UnitTestResult` element (at the very least) encloses your `TestRun` elements.

To have your query take into account the current context, you need to reference the current context.  This can be selected using `.`.

Secondly, your XML elements all have a *namespace*, and this needs to make up part of your query. A prefix needs to be added to a namespace manager, used in your query and the manager passed into the query method.

So, taking these together, define the prefix:

```
var manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
manager.AddNamespace("t", "http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010");
```

Change your query:

```
./t:TestRun/t:TestDefinitions/t:UnitTest[@name='{0}']
```

And pass the namespace manager to the method:

```
trxXml.SelectSingleNode(xpath, manager);
```

XPath and `XmlDocument` are pain, though. This would all be a lot more straightforward in LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(InputTrxFile);

var unitTestQuery = 
    from result in doc.Descendants(ns + "UnitTestResult")
    let name = (string)result.Attribute("testName")
    from unitTest in result.Descendants(ns + "UnitTest")
    where (string)unitTest.Attribute("name") == name
    select unitTest;

var unitTest = unitTestQuery.Single();
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail and clarity of the response. Because the GetElementsByTagName("UnitTestResult") worked I incorrectly assumed that namespace would not be needed.